# c3867'sf::Time::as seconds':non-standard syntax ;use '&'to create a pointer to a member

Tags: c++, sfml

```
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<iostream>
```

int main() {

```
sf::RenderWindow Window;
Window.create(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Game Engine");
sf::Time time = sf::seconds(2);
std::cout << time.asSeconds << std::endl;
while (Window.isOpen()) {
    sf::Event Event;
    while (Window.pollEvent(Event))     {
        if (Event.type ==  sf::Event::Closed) {
            Window.close();
        }

        Window.display();

    }


    {

    }
}
```

}

> 1>------ Build started: Project: SFML-2.0, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   1>  Main.cpp
>   1>c:\users\paribeshpc\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\sfml-2.0\sfml-2.0\main.cpp(11): error C3867: 'sf::Time::asSeconds': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Please help me, I keep getting this error. I was learning sfml from this dued and I copied this code from him but its not working.   [The link to the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxIhVR2w03I&index=2&list=PLHJE4y54mpC5j_x90UkuoMZOdmmL9-_rg#t=20.062015)

Comment: `time.asSeconds()` ?

Answer (score 3):

[`sf::Time::asSeconds`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Time.php#a7538140d095e48da9d7eee015dd455a9) is a *function*, you need to *call* it:

```
std::cout << time.asSeconds() << std::endl;
//                         ^^
//      Note parentheses here
```

What happens right now is that the compiler thinks you want a pointer to the function, which is why it tells you to use the address-of operator `&`.